# Selecting the middle 95% of a grouped resultset in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have the table (below) to log restcalls when testing an API. What I need to do is to exclude the extreme cases (top/bottom 2.5%) for each distinct restcallname within the time interval specified.

The closest I have come so far is the code below returning me a table where the top/bottom 2.5% has been excluded for the entire result.

```
     Column     |            Type             |       Modifiers
----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------
 timestamp      | timestamp without time zone | not null default now()
 testrunid      | character varying(255)      |
 sessionid      | character varying(255)      |
 restcallname   | character varying(255)      |
 completiontime | integer                     |


SELECT 
    restcallname, 
    count(restcallname) as noOfRestCalls, 
    round(avg(completiontime)) as avg_CompletionTime, 
    min(completiontime) as min_CompletionTime, 
    max(completiontime) as max_CompletionTime 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM requests
    WHERE 
        timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 week' 
    ORDER BY
        completiontime
    LIMIT (SELECT (COUNT(*) * 0.95)::integer FROM requests WHERE timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 week')
    OFFSET (SELECT (COUNT(*) * 0.025)::integer FROM requests WHERE timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 week')
) x
GROUP BY 
    restcallname 
ORDER BY 
    restcallname;
```

Any suggestions to solve this or references to similar problems?

Comment: I would recommend you to use the `ntile(1000)` window functions, simply exclude the top and bottom 25 rows based on this value. here is a tuto: http://database-programmer.blogspot.fr/2010/11/really-cool-ntile-window-function.html

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to do this using window functions:

```
SELECT restcallname, 
       count(restcallname) as noOfRestCalls, 
       round(avg(completiontime)) as avg_CompletionTime, 
       min(completiontime) as min_CompletionTime, 
       max(completiontime) as max_CompletionTime 
FROM (SELECT r.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY completiontime) as seqnum,
             COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt
      FROM requests r
      WHERE  timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 week'
     ) r
WHERE seqnum >= 0.025 * cnt AND
      seqnum <= (1 - 0.025) * cnt
GROUP BY restcallname
ORDER BY restcallname;
```

Comment: Probably prettier code, but returns the same set as mine...
Say I have a restcallname getPackages, it needs to select the 95% for this, and so on for any other distinct restcallname

Comment: @NikolajQuorning . . . That seems to be what your question is.  If you want only some of the aggregations to use the 95%, then remove the `where` clause and use conditional aggregation in the `select`.